# DOM Parser - JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom

So through an AJAX Request I receive the following string:

```
  <eventos>
      <evento>
        <local>
          <cidade>Porto</cidade>
          <pais>Portugal</pais>
          <latitude>41.140082</latitude>
          <longitude>-8.622347</longitude>
        </local>
        <artistas>
          <artista>Future Islands</artista>
          <artista>Celebration</artista>
        </artistas>
      </evento>
      <evento>
        <local>
          <cidade>Porto</cidade>
          <pais>Portugal</pais>
          <latitude>41.140082</latitude>
          <longitude>-8.622347</longitude>
       </local>
       <artistas>
         <artista>Fujiya</artista>
         <artista>Rainy Days Factory</artista>
         <artista>O Manipulador</artista>
       </artistas>
     </evento>
   </eventos>
```

Then I proceed to convert her using DOM Parser like this:

```
var xmlDoc;
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
} else {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
}
```

However when I try to loop through its nodes like this for instance:

```
var eventos = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('evento');
alert(eventos.length);
```

It prints 0 although I have 2 of them in the XML. What could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of counter or array, otherwise it's parsing but not accumulating any information.

Edit: Try something like

```
eventosXML.evento.length();
```

Comment: How so? Can you post an example please?

Comment: @AndréSilva Try the above code and see if that gives you the proper length?

Comment: What is the eventosXML?

Comment: Is that not the element that contains the evento?

Comment: The variable that has the string is called 'response'. The one that contains the XML is called 'xmlDoc' so I don't know where that 'eventosXML' came from.